# Heap data structure in python

Tags: python, data-structures, heap

I have implemented min-heap in python, but after some tests I realized that sometimes approximately after every 10th insert it puts it in the wrong position(the parent is larger than child).
The code:

```
class minHeap():
    def __init__(self):
        self.heap = [] # main array
        
    def get_parent(self, i):
        return i//2

    def bubble_up(self):
        i = len(self.heap)-1
        p = self.get_parent(i)
        while self.heap[p] > self.heap[i]:
            self.heap[i], self.heap[p] = self.heap[p], self.heap[i] # swapping parent and child
            i = p
            p = self.get_parent(i)

    def insert(self, k):
        self.heap.append(k)
        self.bubble_up()
```

My last 2 hours has been spent searching for the bug, so I would really appreciate if someone would help me.

Comment: If you really ant some help then please edit your code so it is a [mre] - include imports and some minimal data - so that anyone can paste the code into a file and _without adding anything_ run your code to see the same problem.

Comment: Your code still isn’t a [mre] - you need to include some code to create an instance of the class/call your methods, with some data, and show how you know the allocation is ‘wrong’. Try it yourself as if you were reading this question - what do you need to add to the code in the question to see the same result as the person asking the question? Now add this additional code so anyone can run the code in your question __without adding anything__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

You should change this function from

```
def get_parent(self, i):
    return i//2
```

To:

```
def get_parent(self, i):
    return (i-1)//2
```

---

### Explanation

You are using a list in python to initialize which is `0-indexed`.

```
self.heap = [] # main array
```

Now, Let's say you have added 2 elements 1 and 5.

> self.heap = [1,5]

Now. If you add one more element which is 3.

> self.heap = [1,5,3]

Now, **index of 3 is 2**. It's *parent should be 1(index = 0)*. But **i//2** will give you 5(index = 1) as `2//2 = 1`.

So, you should use `(i-1)//2` which will give you **0**.

> **(2-1)//2 = 0**

---

Hoping that you have understood my solution.

---

Comment: @TLado Could you accept my answer if you found that useful?

Comment: Thanks, you have helped me a lot. One problem I had to solve after was that sometimes I got -1 as the index of the parent, which would screw up the entire code. The problem there was that the root node doesn't have a parent, that is why I had to make a base case. After that, the heap worked perfectly.